# Is there any benefit to checking the count before clear?

Tags: c#, .net

I see so many people do this in C#...

```
if (someDictionary.Count > 0) {
    someDictionary.Clear();
}
```

The question I have is, why not just `.Clear` it? What is the deal with this? Should I check the count before clearing or is it simply just useless and doesn't do anything different?

More importantly im confused why I see it so often.

Comment: I've never seen that. It's ridiculous. It looks like folk optimization to me. Don't bother. If you see it often, read better code.

Comment: From `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation: `public void Clear() {            if (count > 0) { ... }}`. You might think you save a method call, but `Count` is a property and its a method call as well

Comment: The [first line](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) in the source code of Dictionary.Clear is _if(count > 0)_

Comment: @EdPlunkett Just because you've never seen it doesn't mean it doesn't happen. I've seen all sorts of weird "optimisations" (and in my younger days I've done them myself - I possibly still do and won't realise for a while yet)

Comment: @ColinMackay Who are you talking to? Obviously if OP sees it, it happens. The fact that I haven't seen it is perfectly irrelevant to whether it happens in code I haven't seen. However, the fact that at least one experienced developer has never seen it does suggest that maybe it's not as common as OP assumed based on the code *he* has seen. "Why does everybody do this?" "Not everybody does". See?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the source code for [Dictionary.Clear()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,216) you'll see it does the check itself.

```
    public void Clear() {
        if (count > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; i++) buckets[i] = -1;
            Array.Clear(entries, 0, count);
            freeList = -1;
            count = 0;
            freeCount = 0;
            version++;
        }
    }
```

So, doing the check outside seems to be a waste of time.

Why do folks do this? Possibly because it seems to make sense to not do work if you don't have to, and if you don't know what the implementation is you might think you are gaining something.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary. The `Clear()` method actually does it itself, as you can tell from the [Reference Implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs):

```
public void Clear() {
    if (count > 0) {
         /* omitted for brevity */
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about what and why other people do things like this, there are so many ways to skin the cat, so many different use cases in software, bad practices, etc... that we will never know why things like this are done.

What we do know is there is no need to check the count first unless you have a case to do it. Calling clear on a collection will clear it and if it is already empty, it will do nothing and move on (ie no exception will be thrown). There is little to no performance impact either, in fact, one could argue it is actually slower to check the count first if you know you are going to clear it anyway.